# Custom Bootstrap validation on form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am collecting an ABN (Australian Business Number) on a registration form. I have written some javascript that does validation based on the ABN validation rule here:

function validateABN (abnNumber) {

```
var weights = [10, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19];
var result = false;

if (abnNumber.length === 11) {

    var sum = 0;
    var weight;

    for (var index = 0; index <= weights.length - 1; index++) {
        weight = weights[index];
        digit = abnNumber[index] - (index ? 0 : 1);
        sum += weight * digit;
    }

    result = sum % 89 === 0;
}

return result;
}
console.log(validateABN('43154365778'));
```

The form field name is: CompanyABNACN

It is a bootstrap form. I'm a little familiar with bootstrap but not to the point where I can add custom form field validation on a form element. I want an error message to be displayed "Invalid ABN format" if the javascript validation fails.

I have searched google and within the stack overflow forums and have not been able to find an example similar to mine or I have found really complicated examples I'm not able to understand.

Would someone please explain to me how to incorporate this custom function into validation on my registration form please.

```
<div class="account-hold my-account register">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-30">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1 class="my-account-label">Create Account</h1><hr class="ghr">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right">
                <img src="assets/images/content-images/register/image.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p class="my-account-label-p mb-30">Already have an account? <a href="/login/">Click here</a> to sign in or complete the form below to create a new account</p>
                <form name="registrationform" id="registration-form" action="/registration/" method="post" class="form-horizontal validate-form" role="form">
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="register" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="/content/thank-you-registration/" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="validated" value="f" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label my_acct_lbl">First Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="" class="form-control required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label my_acct_lbl">Last Name :</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname"  placeholder="" class="form-control required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label my_acct_lbl">Email Address :</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <input name="email" type="email" id="registration-email"  placeholder="" class="form-control required email" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label my_acct_lbl">ABN :</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <input name="CompanyABNACN" type="text" id="CompanyABNACN" placeholder="" class="form-control required is-invalid"  />
                            <div class="form-control hidden invalid-feedback">Please provide a valid ABN.</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label my_acct_lbl">Company :</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <input name="CompanyName" type="text" id="CompanyName"  placeholder="" class="form-control required company" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label my_acct_lbl">Phone Number :</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <input name="PhoneNumber" type="text" id="PhoneNumber"  placeholder="" class="form-control phone-number" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                            <input name="birthday" type="hidden" id="birthday" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label my_acct_lbl">Capricorn Member Number:</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <input name="capicorn_number" type="text" id="capicorn_number" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label my_acct_lbl">Street Address :</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <input name="streetaddress" type="text" id="street-address"  placeholder="" class="form-control street-address required auto-streetaddress" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label my_acct_lbl">Suburb / City :</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <input name="suburb" type="text" id="suburb"  placeholder="" class="form-control city required auto-suburb" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label my_acct_lbl">State :</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <select name="state" class="form-control required auto-state" id="state">
                                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                    <option value="ACT">Australian Capital Territory</option>
                                    <option value="NSW">New South Wales</option>
                                    <option value="NT ">Northern Territory</option>
                                    <option value="QLD">Queensland</option>
                                    <option value="SA ">South Australia</option>
                                    <option value="TAS">Tasmania</option>
                                    <option value="VIC">Victoria</option>
                                    <option value="WA ">Western Australia</option>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label my_acct_lbl">Country : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <select name="country" id="Country" class="form-control clone required auto-country" data-native-menu="false" data-rel="country-field">
                                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                <option value="Australia" >Australia</option>
                                <option value="New Zealand" >New Zealand</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label my_acct_lbl">Post Code : </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <input name="postcode" type="text" id="postcode" class="form-control required auto-postcode" placeholder="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!---
                    <input type="hidden" name="password">
                    <input type="hidden" name="password2">
                    --->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label my_acct_lbl">Account Password :</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control required" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label my_acct_lbl">Confirm Password :</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control required" id="password2" name="password2" data-rel="password" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 control-label label">Newsletter: </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter1" id="newsletter1" value="1" checked="true">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-3 col-md-offset-4 col-md-3 text-left">
                            <input name="submitbutton" id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Register" class="btn partwise-btn btn-block text-uppercase" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML.

Comment: hi @kmoser I've included the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify when the validation should occur, e.g. as the user is entering the ABN number or when they submit the form. Assuming the former, you can do the following:

1. Add an 'input' event listener to the ABN input field so that it validates every time the user enters something in that field:

```html
<input name="CompanyABNACN" type="text" id="CompanyABNACN" placeholder="" class="form-control required is-invalid" oninput="do_validate();" />
```

(You can also use jQuery to add an event listener rather than doing it inline as in my example above.)

2. Your validation function should look something like this:

```js
function do_validate() {
    if ( validateABN( $('input#CompanyABNACN').val() ) ) {
        $( '.invalid-feedback' ).hide();
        $('input#CompanyABNACN').removeClass( 'is-invalid' )
    } else {
        $( '.invalid-feedback' ).show();
        $('input#CompanyABNACN').addClass( 'is-invalid' )
    }
}
```

Comment: @WebsiteBuilder You're welcome! If my response answered your question, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "`is-invalid`" class to the input to invalidate for ABN via javascript.

```
<div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
      <label for="ABNnumber">Zip</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ABNnumber" name="ABNnumber" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid ABN.
      </div>
    </div>
```

Your javascript should be sth like this

```
$("form#abnFormSubmit").on("submit", function(e){
e.preventdefault;
     var isAbnValid = validateABN($("#ABNnumber").val());
if(!isAbnValid){
$("#ABNnumber").addClass("is-invalid");
}
else{
$("#ABNnumber").removeClass("is-invalid");
}
})
```

Comment: <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please provide a valid ABN.
      </div> Just appears on the page all the time.

Comment: Editted answer add a else statement to removeClass("is-invalid"). Check the updated html and js.

Comment: The invalid-feedback class is to highlight the input that is invalid after validation. What version of bootstrap are you using. Also ensure all scripts are loaded.